# How to dynamically select inside a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have this dilemma I am creating a procedure that uses a table from another database inside it. Say:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspRetrieveCurrentPropertyDate (
@InternalEntityId VARCHAR(10)
,@InternalUserId VARCHAR(10)
,@InternalSiteId VARCHAR(10) --this is the database I need to get the table from
)
as begin
...
...
select TOP 1 arsDailyCtlDate from @InternalSiteId..AccountsSetting
end
```

but of course it will return an error.

The original script uses something like:

```
SET @cSQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 arsDailyCtlDate FROM  S' + @SiteID + '.dbo.AccountsSetting WITH (NOLOCK)'

EXEC(@cSQL)
```

to accomplish the task. But I wanted to rewrite the code. Is there anyway I can do it the way I like it to be done? Without using exec(@cSQL)?

Thanks,
Sherwin

Comment: nop! there is no other way .

Comment: Well, you do have to use dynamic sql, but instead of EXEC() you could use sp_executesql().

Comment: What kind of error would it return? Why not use naming convention for selecting from another database like: `databasename.schemaname.tablename` in your dynamic sql? Also, using `sp_executesql` is recommended if you don't want to open doors for sql injection.

Comment: @NepaliRookie - database names in the query can't be parameterised, you're forced to write a literal value in to the sql statement, so using `sp_executesql` won't protect from sql injection attacks here.  Best option is to check the parameter against a white list before injecting the database name in to the dynamic sql.

Comment: @MatBailie I suppose you are right in this case, it wouldn't matter much. But still recommended to use sp_executesql.

Comment: You really should wrap your tablename in QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection. Also, why the nolock hint? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? It is NOT a magic go fast feature. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And I also notice you have top 1 but no order by. That means you don't know which row you will get back.

Comment: Hi everyone! **Thank you** so much for your inputs. I have no other option but to stick with `exec` or `sp_executesql`.

@SeanLange Our DBAs require us (developers) to use `NOLOCK` since we are querying from accounting tables (with millions of data).

Seems that I have much more to learn. Thank you again, guys!

Comment: HOLY CRAP!!!! An accounting system is exactly the worst time to use NOLOCK. Sadly your senior DBAs drank the kool-aid that nolock is simply dirty reads. It is so much more than that. When accuracy is important that is about the worst thing you can do. With that much data doing something like snapshot isolation may be a much better choice than the current mantra. I have been in your situation and feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

There IS one way you can do what you need without dynamic SQL, but it is a maintenance nightmare.   You can do this:

```
IF @InternalSiteId = 'DatabaseA'
  SELECT TOP 1 arsDailyCtlDate  FROM DatabaseA..AccountsSetting
ELSE IF @InternalSiteId = 'DatabaseB'
  SELECT TOP 1 arsDailyCtlDate  FROM DatabaseB..AccountsSetting
ELSE IF @InternalSiteId = 'DatabaseC'
  SELECT TOP 1 arsDailyCtlDate  FROM DatabaseC..AccountsSetting
```

And so on for every possible database the user could choose.   As you add new databases you will need to update the proc to handle them.

You're probably better off with the dynamic sql solution, but this would work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I consulted my senior and yes, he said that there is no other way to do it but to use  EXEC() or sp_executesql().